# Fastest way to store char[][] in shared preferences

Tags: java, android, multidimensional-array, sharedpreferences, arrays

In my app, the main set of data is a two-dimensional char array (`char[][]`), in which some of the values may be non-printable characters and even `\0` characters.  What would be the fastest way to store this array in the shared prefs and retrieve it later?  Speed of retrieval is a lot more important to me than the speed of saving it.  The arrays are not particularly large, probably no more than 100x100.

Presently, I'm converting it into a string by simply concatenating all characters, row-by-row, column-by-column, and storing the string along with the dimensions (as int).

I have also considered just serialising the array (`writeObject` into a `ByteArrayOutputStreram` and then use the stream's `toString` method), but haven't tried it yet.

Any other suggestions?  Again, the fastest possible retrieval (and recreation as the char[][] array) is my primary concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `StringSet` methods (put and get) are only available from Android 3.0 and also because I found the preferences being less than reliable when storing long strings, especially those containing 0-chars, I use a different way of storing data in the app.

I use internal files (`fileGetInput` and `fileGetOutput`), I then create a `HashMap<Integer, char[][]>` and write it to the file using `writeObject`.  As I have a few of those char arrays, identified by an integer ID, this way I'm saving them all in one go.

I do realise that I may be loosing something in terms of performance, however in this case reliability comes first.

Answer (score 0):

I posted you a way which uses many native functions and therefore is likely fast. Be aware that this is untested and shall only be used inspirational.

```
public void save(char[][] chars) {
    Set<String> strings = new LinkedHashSet<String>(chars.length);

    for(int i = 0, len = chars.length; i < len; i++) {
        strings[i] = new String(chars[i]);
    }

    getSharedPreferences().edit().putStringSet("data", strings).commit();
}

public char[][] read() {
    Set<String> strings = getSharedPreferences().getStringSet("data", new LinkedHashSet<String>());

    char[][] chars = new char[strings.size][];
    int i = 0;

    for(String line : strings) {
        chars[i++] = line.toCharArray();
    }

    return chars;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but, unfortunately, `StringSet` methods on preferences are only available from Android 3.0 onwards.  My app needs to work from 1.6 above.

Comment: Ok, i see the weakness of my solution. A small tip: When you're concerned about performance, use ArrayList<char[]> or [SparseArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html)<char[]> instead of HashMap<Integer, char[]>.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose while I have only 3-4 items in the collection, it's not much of a deal, but with the size of it growing, I'll definitely make a change.